# Combining two BVH animations. One has hand data, the other has body data

Tags: animation, bvh

I have hand pose data and body data animations that I need to stack on top of each other (with the NLA editor?). How do I combine them in a way  that ignores the hand data for the body animation and ignores the body data for the hand animations.

I am using brekel to record mocap data for the body and hands separately. Both files are recorded simultaneously. How do I combine the two BVH files in blender?

Here are the two files I am working with:

https://uploadfiles.io/uhns9
https://uploadfiles.io/jp4ky

Answer (score 0):

1. Open 3D editor and DopeSheet.
2. In DopeSheet click on the little mouse cursor button, so you will see only the selected.
3. (Pose mode) Select all the hand bones of your hand animated skeleton and all of their keys and click on the copy button.
4. (Pose mode) Select all of the handbones of your second skeleton, and delete all of their keys except the firsts.
5. Click on the paste button.

[image]

Comment: please message me on discord AmpleClarity#1469 ...I had messsages disabled earlier by accident